# How can I install and run R on an iPad?

Tags: ipad, software

I teach a class that uses R as part of the lab and one of my students uses an iPad for her primary computer.  Is there anyway to install R on an iPad?

I found some old blog posts that say it isn't possible but I have not been able to find any information less than about 5 years old.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple, in that, if it is not in the app store it can't be installed, unless you want to go the jailbreak route because you found an "R" app for jailbroken IOS devices.

Answer (score 2):

There is an app called [Analyser](https://appsto.re/us/TWEJab.i) by You Hui Yan available on the App Store ($14.95) which includes a R interpreter as well as a Python interpreter. The `install.packages()` is disabled (per Apple's requirements), but a fairly broad number of libraries are included. The last update was in 2017, so it is still active.

Comment: Scroll through the description. The author talks about the python engine before the r engine. Can't use install.packages but you can use source() and iTunes file sharing as well as read.table() with url's

Comment: @user3674944 is correct, you can't use install.packages(). That is an Apple-imposed limitation. However  you can use iTunes File Sharing, iMazing, and iFunBox to add files into the Documents directory and any sub-directories you happen to create. Also library() works just fine as do functions like readRDS() and lazyLoad().  Apple's restrictions (see 2.5.2 in the guidelines) prohibit the addition of compiled code. There is no restriction on, say, serialized database (*.rdx) files.   <p> The recent update has added many common packages, including the tidyverse.

Answer (score 1):

As a followup to @Rodrigo, iSH is now available on the App Store, without **apk** (the Alpine package manager). The [instructions](https://github.com/ish-app/ish/wiki/Installing-apk) to install apk are on the [iSH](https://github.com/ish-app/ish/wiki) wiki.

After that, it is a simple to install R, as @Rodrigo noted, and details on adding  compiled packages are [here](https://github.com/ish-app/ish/wiki/Installing-R-and-any-package-from-the-CRAN).

emacs is also available from apk, and thus, possibly, [ess](https://ess.r-project.org/index.php?Section=download) (not tested).

If you wish to use an iPad editor (e.g. [Textastic](https://www.textasticapp.com) or [Buffer](https://buffereditor.com)), you can use `mount -t iOS foo /mountpoint` to mount a directory that the editor can also access. Files can also be transferred locally via the files app. (tested.)

It is unclear if RStudio can be built for iSH.

Answer (score 0):

Let her try this site: [TutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/codingground.htm), where she can use [R](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/r_terminal_online.php) or [R-Studio](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_r_online.php).

Also, this [RollApp](https://www.rollapp.com/app/rstudio) may be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can download an ios app from the appstore to connect via ssh to another machine in your network with R already installed

Answer (score 0):

I setup Rstudio on Win10 with Amazon's workspaces. The cost is reasonable at 7.95/mo and 22 cents/hr of use for the basic tier. There is an Amazon Workspaces iOS app that actually seems to be usable.

I am not that interested in programming on my iPad. I am more interested in running programs and seeing the output. This definitely is feasible with Amazon Workspaces. But programming might actually be feasible. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

You can install R (but not run it perfectly) without jailbreak. First you'll need to get [ISH app](https://ish.app) which is a Linux (Alpine) emulator. To do that you need to download the [Testflight app](https://testflight.apple.com) from the App Store which is an app for beta testing other apps. Then you'll need to click the invite at the [ISH app's](https://ish.app) website from yout Ipad. You'll be prompted to download the ISH app. Once on the App you'll open a terminal emulator. Type

> apk add R

to install R (I also suggest):

> apk add R-dev R-doc

Then you'll get R in your ipad.

Caveats: packages that need compiling won't work well here as this is an emulator.